# Selecting and changing an image in a block

Tags: javascript, jquery

When choosing a picture in a block, I need to switch the main picture

Where do I start?

Comment: A "libraries" for this easy task? No, study `querySelectorAll`( [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) ),  `click event`( [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) ), `innerHTML`( [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) ).

Comment: Note: asking for a library is **off-topic** on SO and likely to get your question closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JavaScript function which could do it,

```
function SlideShow(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("");
  var circles = document.getElementsByClassName("");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slidePosition = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slidePosition = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].className = circles[i].className.replace(" enable", "");
  }
  slides[slidePosition-1].style.display = "block";
  circles[slidePosition-1].className += " enable";
}
```

And of course CSS!

Or you can use *onclick* methods to make another way of functionality.

Comment: yes, I need that when clicking on `img-to-select`, it becomes `main`, most likely through `onclick` it will be better

Comment: yes onclick would be deff easier to make it work better. hope my answer help. upvote if you liked!